# repeated random sampling; sampling distribution of sample median

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

need help with repeated random sampling! given population size 10,000 people of 3 age groups exist: 2000 of age '1-10', 3000 of age '11-20' and 5000 of age '21-30'. Monthly salary of Each age group is normally distributed as in the following: age '1-10' : mean = 2000, variance = 500^2 age '11-20': mean = 3000, variance = 600^2 age '21-30': mean = 4000, variance = 700^2

note: age-group composition of the sample must be same or close to the age group composition of the population i.e. age '1-10' group constitutes 20% of the sample or 0.2x50 = 10. objective: perform repeated random sampling of size 50 from the population and find sampling distribution of sample median monthly salary. instruction: do it with 400 repeated sampling outcomes and visualise the sampling distribution simulated.

this is what I did:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as pet
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
population = 10000
repeat = 400
samplesize = 50
samplesize_list = [10, 15, 25]
label_list = ['1-10', '11-20', '21-30']
std_list = [500, 600, 700]
mean_list = [2000, 3000, 4000]
repeat_median = np.empty(repeat, dtype = float)
for j in range(Len(samplesize_list)):
    size = samplesize_list[j]
    for i in range(repeat):
        sample_data = np.random.normal(mean_list[i], std_list[i], size)
        repeat.median[I] = np.median(sample_data)
plt.subplot(len(samplesize_list), 1, j+1)
sns.distplot(repeat_median, colour = 'blue', label = label_list[j])
plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
plt.show()
```

not sure where I went wrong in my code but I can't seem to get the results I want

Answer (score 1):

There were lots of errors in your code. I rectified them and present the working code below. I am not showing the initial lines of the code where you define the data. I am highlighting the modified lines by a comment `#`.

Just couple of more points: length is calculated using `len` instead of `Len`, the correct spelling for specifying colors is `color` and not `colour`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # You wrote plt as pet

for j in range(len(samplesize_list)): # Replaced Len by len
    size = samplesize_list[j]
    for i in range(repeat):
        sample_data = np.random.normal(mean_list[j], std_list[j], size) # replaced j-->i
        repeat_median[i] = np.median(sample_data) # Corrected
    plt.subplot(len(samplesize_list), 1, j+1)
    sns.distplot(repeat_median,  color='blue', label = label_list[j]) # Modified
    plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
plt.tight_layout() # Added for better adjustment of spacing
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: hi! why did u use 'j' in place of 'I' in the code of sample_data = np.random.normal(mean_list[j], std_list[j], size) ?

Comment: Because your list had only three elements. Thats the correct indexing. Go through the code carefully And you will understand